# Python plot 365-days yearly data in a color

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

A sample data of my original dataframe is given below. Original dataframe has 20 years data.

```
input_df =             
Datetime         Data             
2000-05-31       0.000
2000-06-20       8.204
2000-06-21       7.724
2000-06-22       7.268
2000-06-23       3.687
2017-01-03       2.718
2017-01-04       3.113
2017-01-05       3.841
2017-01-06       4.135
2017-01-07       0.819
2017-01-08       3.537
2017-01-09       3.471
```

I want to plot above data such that I want to achieve following figure representing one color and marker for one year data.

[image]

I tried the solution my way but did not work. 
My solution:

```
year_group = input_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='A'),axis=1)    
years = pd.DataFrame()
for name, group in year_group:
    years[name.year] = group.values
years.plot(subplots=True, legend=False)
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
# dummy data
dti = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=20*12, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(20*12,)), index=dti, columns=['value'])

import itertools
marker = itertools.cycle(['.', ',', 'o', 'v', '^', '<', '>', '1', '2', '3', '4', '8', 's', 'p', '*', 'h', 'H', '+', 'x', 'D', 'd', '|', '_', 'P', 'X'])

for y in range(2000,2020):
    temp = df.loc[df.index.year==y]
    plt.plot(temp.index.dayofyear, temp.value, label=y, marker=next(marker))
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: I implemented your method. Got following error: `return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value'`